# jQuery UI not loaded in custom lightning component for community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, jquery, community-builder

I am trying to include jQueryUI version 1.12.0 in one of my lightning component (I need it for autocomplete). That lightning component is used in community builder.

What I did was to include jQUery and jQeuryUI like this,

```
    <ltng:require scripts="/resource/jQuery_3_1_0,/resource/jQueryUI_1_12_0" 
              styles="/resource/jQueryUICSS"
              afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.init}" />
```

The strange thing is that in one of the environments it does load while in another environment it does not (I have ensure Static Resources are correct).

On the environment it does not load I do get a warning,

'Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/. in aura_prod.js:345

I am open to suggestions if anyone knows how to achieve auto complete without jueryui (I did try typeahead that didn't work as well)

Comment: I tried loading the resources one at a time, jQuery and jQueryUICSS do load but not jQueryUI

Comment: try the jquery UI latest version this will help you.

Comment: isn't jQuery UI 1.12.0 the latest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locker service for communities had to be disabled from critical updates.